# Transferring file net

Tags: node.js, pipe

I would like to transfer files between one client, and a server.
I only use stream, and fs modules.

For the moment, I can transfer ".txt" files perfectly, but it does not work for ".mp3" files (for instance). Indeed, the size of the ".mp3" file saved from the server has a bigger size than the original file. (eg : 9,2 mo instead of 5mo) and I can not open it.

Here is my server part:

```
var net = require('net');
var util = require("util");
var fs = require('fs');
var receive_object = {};
var server = net.createServer(function (socket){    

  console.log('server connected');

  socket.write('hello\r\n');

  //socket.pipe(socket);     
      socket.on('data',function(data){              
        if(data.toString() == "upload_demand"){
        socket.write("upload_demand_ok");
      }else if(data.toString().indexOf("fileName")>-1){
        data = data.toString().replace("fileName","");
        fs.exists("server_"+data, function(exists){
          if(exists) socket.write("fileName_ko");
          else{            
            receive_object.fileName = data;
            receive_object.writable = fs.createWriteStream("server_"+receive_object.fileName);
            receive_object.contenu = "";
            socket.write("fileName_ok");
          }
        });
      }else if(data.toString().indexOf("size")>-1){
        data = data.toString().replace("size","");
        receive_object.size_total = data;        
        receive_object.size_received = 0;        
        socket.write("size_ok");
      }/*else if(data.toString()=="upload_success"){        
        receive_object.writable.write(receive_object.contenu);          
          console.log('It\'s saved!');        
      }*/
      else{        
        receive_object.size_received += 64*1024;
        socket.write("uploading"+parseInt(receive_object.size_received/receive_object.size_total*100));
        receive_object.contenu += data;
      }

      });

    socket.on('end', function() {
        console.log('client disconnected');      
      receive_object.writable.write(receive_object.contenu);    
  });//socket on
});
/**
let's listening the server
*/
server.listen(1337, '127.0.0.1',function(){
    console.log("server bound on port %j and on address %j",server.address().port,server.address().address);    
});
```

Here is my client part:

```js
var util = require("util");
var net = require("net");
var fs = require('fs');
var fileName = "exemple.txt";

/**
client connecting to the corresponding port Server
*/
var client = net.connect({port: 1337}, function () {
  util.log("Client connected");
  fs.exists(fileName, function(exists) {
    if (exists) {   
      fs.stat(fileName, function(error, stats) {
        transfer_object = {};
        transfer_object.fileName = fileName;
        transfer_object.size = stats.size;      
        transfer_object.stream = fs.createReadStream(fileName, { bufferSize: 64 * 1024 });
        transfer_object.progression = 0;
        client.write("upload_demand");
      });
    }else{
        console.log("fileNotFound");
    }
  });
});

client.on('data', function(data) {
  if(data=="upload_demand_ok"){
    console.log(''+data);
    client.write("fileName"+transfer_object.fileName);
  }
  else if(data == "fileName_ok"){
    console.log(''+data);
    client.write("size"+transfer_object.size)
  }else if(data == "fileName_ko"){
    console.log('ficher deja existant');
  }else if(data == "size_ok"){    
    console.log(''+data);
    transfer_object.stream.pipe(client,{ end: true });
  }else if(data.toString().indexOf("uploading")>-1){
    data = parseInt(data.toString().replace("uploading",""));
    progressbar(data);
    //if(data>=100) client.write('upload_success');
  }
});
/**
client receive end event from server
*/
client.on('end', function() {
  console.log('client disconnected');
});

function progressbar(int){
  if(int>=0 && int<=20 && transfer_object.progression == 0){
    transfer_object.progression = 1;
    process.stdout.write("progression : [=");
  }
  else if(int>20 && int<=40 && transfer_object.progression == 1){
    transfer_object.progression = 2;
    process.stdout.write("==");
  }else if(int>40 && int<=60 && transfer_object.progression == 2){
    transfer_object.progression = 3;
    process.stdout.write("==");
  }else if(int>60 && int<=80 && transfer_object.progression == 3){
    transfer_object.progression = 4;
    process.stdout.write("==");
  }else if(int>80 && int<=100 && transfer_object.progression == 4){
    transfer_object.progression = 5;
    process.stdout.write("=]");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The txt file has utf8 encoding, and the mp3 - binary encoding.
You can set the encoding usable for stream as described here http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_write_chunk_encoding_callback

According to http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffer
The `utf8` is for txt, and `binary` for mp3 data (but manual do not recommend using it)